# Instalação do MongoDB no Debian

Tags: mongodb, linux

Estou tentando rodar o MongoDB no Debian Jessie e aparentemente instala tudo corretamente, mas quando executo dá erros conforme indicados abaixo. Não sei se é relevante também, mas seguindo a página de instalação do MongoDB, é apresentado o comando `apt-get install -y mongodb-org` para instalar o MongoDB, mas só consegui fazer com que instalasse ao executar `apt-get install -y mongodb`, sem o `-org` no final.
OBS.: Eu estava logado como root.

Erro executando `systemctl start mongodb`:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf (code=exited, status=100) Main PID: 6939 (code=exited, status=100)
```

Erro executando `service mongod restart`:

```
Failed to restart mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.
```

O que pode estar ocorrendo?

Comment: Se você tentar iniciar o mongo direto via mongod, funciona? Assim você consegue saber se o problema está na instalação ou na configuração do serviço.

Comment: Não funciona... já tinha tentado. Mas acho que já entendi o problema: é que estou tentando instalar o MongoDB num dispositivo Linux com processador ARM, mas não há suporte para esse processador. Enfim, acho que vou ter que trocar de banco de dados.

Comment: Existe uma versão para processadores ARM sim, nos downloads você consegue selecionar isso, o link da versão 3.4.6 aqui: https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-arm64-ubuntu1604-3.4.6.tgz

Comment: Olá, bom dia. Isso também aconteceu comigo recentemente. No meu caso, estava instalando no Ubuntu 14.04. Uma pergunta: qual a arquitetura do Debian? 32 ou 64bit? A explicação que consegui foi que no repositório somente havia instalador para a versão de x64. Forte abraço. Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: @PauloPereira, no meu caso era arquitetura ARM 32 bits. Eu estava com pressa, acabei abandonando o MongoDB e usei MySQL, que naquela oportunidade resolveu tudo muito bem, como sempre aliás...